# Limit number of toggled switch on bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/ is there script so that I can limit the number of toggled switches. Here is my code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(argument) {
    $('[type="checkbox"]').bootstrapSwitch();
    var limit = 5;
    $('[type="checkbox"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
      //event listener
    });
  });
</script>
```

```html
 <input type="checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox">
```

Please let me have any idea on how to do this. Thanks

Comment: can you please explain further what you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: I have 5 toggle switch. What I want is I only want (n) number of  switches to be turned on. If (n) number of switches is enabled, if user attempts to toggle on another switch, it should show alert message then will not toggle on the switch pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional event handler for click event, which can cancel the switchChange before it triggers bootstrapSwitch. Like this :

```
$('[type="checkbox"]').on('click',function(e) {
       if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
         e.preventDefault();
         alert("You have already reached the limit");
         return false;
       }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 $('[type="checkbox"]').bootstrapSwitch();

 var limit = 2;
 $('[type="checkbox"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {

   if ($('[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > limit) {
     $(this).bootstrapSwitch('state', !state, true);
     alert('You are allowed to check a maximum of ' + limit + ' options')
   }
 });
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lj1v6nvs/1/

Comment: This works fine. It alerts however I do not want toggle on to push through.

Comment: I already solved it. Thanks for help.  this line solved the issue `$(this).bootstrapSwitch('toggleState');`

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this -

```
var limit = 5;
$('[type="checkbox"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
    if($('[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > limit ) {
        alert('You are allowed to check '+limit+' options'); /*show alert when more than limit are selected*/
        $(this).prop('checked', false); /* uncheck the last one checked*/
    }
});
```